# Making Header Responsive in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Complete newbie to Bootstrap. I am in the process of creating a responsive one page site with Bootstrap V3. I have all the elements working however I cannot get the header to resize responsively. CSS is below:

```
.header-image {
background: url(../images/header_test.jpg) no-repeat;
background-position: top;
height: auto;
display: block;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: Sorry as I mentioned i am a real novice. Where would I input the .img-responsive class into the css?

Thanks again
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 has a built in class `.img-responsive` for responsive images.

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-responsive-images

Comment: Sorry as I mentioned i am a real novice. Where would I input the .img-responsive class into the css?

Thanks again
Andrew

Comment: First, i would remove your custom class from your css, then add the `.img-responsive` class to your `img` element within your HTML. Then if there are still changes that need to be made, you can add a second class to your `img` element with any custom CSS that needs to be applied.

Comment: Thank you. This worked like a charm. Bit of a work around to get it working. Thanks again

Comment: If this worked, please except this as the answer to the question.